# React JSX Spread Attribute in cloneElement

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and got stuck. Maybe someone can help. I have the following code:

React-router

```
ReactDOM.render(

   <Router> 
       <Route path="/" component={App}>
           <Route path="something" component={Something} />
       </Route>
   </Router>

,document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

App

```
var App = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        status: 'ready',
        title: 'The Title'
    }
},

render: function() {

    var childComp = null;

    if(this.props.children) {

            /*
                This will work 
                childComp = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {title: this.state.title, status: this.state.status});
            */

            /*this wont*/
            childComp = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.state});
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={this.state.title} />
            {childComp}
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Something:

```
var Something = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Something</h1>
            <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
            <h3>{this.props.status}</h3>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

The problem is that App can have many many states. I dont want to manually write them like so:

```
React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {title: this.state.title, status: this.state.status})
```

But using JSX spread attributes wont work (syntaxerror)

Comment: What are you using to transpile your JSX? Babel in particular (with the correct settings/presets) handles this correctly; see the example at http://bit.ly/1QvbFTA

Comment: Yes it seems i have a problem in my webpack configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.state)` should work.